# How add dataset into report c#

Tags: c#, sql, windows, winforms, crystal-reports

Hello I have problem on create report with crystal report c#,
I should insert the result of this SqlAdapter in a c # report , but do not know how to do

```
String Query = "SELECT Utente.LogoAzienda,Preventivo.DataInserimento,Preventivo.RiferimentoInterno,Preventivo.Testata,Preventivo.Chiusura,Cliente.Titolo,Cliente.RagioneSociale,Cliente.Indirizzo,Cliente.Cap,Cliente.Citta,Cliente.Provincia  FROM Preventivo  inner join Cliente  on Cliente.IdCliente = Preventivo.IdCliente  inner join Utente  on Preventivo.UtenteCreazione = Utente.Username";

SqlConnection conn = db.apriconnessione();

DataStampaPreventivoCompleto d = new DataStampaPreventivoCompleto();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Query, conn);
da.Fill(d, d.Tables[0].TableName);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example to bind dataset to crystal report:

```
private void CrystalFormView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlbill"].ConnectionString;
  string provider = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlbill"].ProviderName;
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);
  SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select product as Product,productid as ProductId,quantity as Quantity from productdata", con);

  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  sda.Fill(ds);
  ds.Tables[0].TableName = "BILLTEST";

  BillCrystalReport bill = new BillCrystalReport();  
  bill.SetDataSource(ds);

  bill.VerifyDatabase();

  crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = bill;
  crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
}
```

For more, please check this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/754037/Bind-Crystal-Reports-with-Dataset-or-Datatable

Comment: i have try your code but visual studio print this message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet1\crdb_adoplus.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: @RikiDev it's good ettiquette to post the solution to the problem, rather than "fixed it", so other people who may find this thread will be able to solve it too.